# Perl: remove a part of string after pattern

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

I have strings like this:

```
trn_425374_1_94_-
trn_12_1_200_+
trn_2003_2_198_+
```

And I want to split all after the first number, like this:

```
trn_425374
trn_12
trn_2003
```

I tried the following code:

```
$string =~ s/(?<=trn_\d)\d+//gi;
```

But returns the same as the input. I have been following examples of similar questions but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do grouping to save first numbers of digits found and use `.*` to delete from there until end of line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    s/(\d+).*$/$1/ && print;
}

__DATA__
trn_425374_1_94_-
trn_12_1_200_+
trn_2003_2_198_+
```

It yields:

```
trn_425374
trn_12
trn_2003
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Perl 5 version 10 or later then you have access to the `\K` ("keep") regular expression escape. Everything before the `\K` is excluded from the substitution, so this removes everything after the first sequence of digits (except newlines)

```
s/\d+\K.+//;
```

with earlier versions of Perl, you will have to *capture* the part of the string you want to keep, and replace it in the substitution

```
s/(\D*\d+).+/$1/;
```

Note that neither of these will remove any trailing newline characters. If you want to strip those as well, then either `chomp` the string first, or add the `/s` modifier to the substitution, like this

```
s/\d+\K.+//s;
```

or

```
s/(\D*\d+).+/$1/s;
```

Answer (score 0):

your regexr should be:

```
$string =~ s/(trn_\d+).*/$1/g;
```

It substitutes the whole match by the memorized at $1 (which is the string part you want to preserve)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc) to preserve the part of the string you want to keep:

```
$string =~ s/trn_\d+\K.*//;
```

To quote the link above:

> \K
>
> This appeared in perl 5.10.0. Anything matched left of \K is not
>   included in $& , and will not be replaced if the pattern is used in a
>   substitution.